# udl file for remote oracle database connection string

Tags: oracle, connection-string, remote-server

I want to create a connection string using udl file to my remote oracle 12c server residing say on xyz....url on port number 1521 with the required username and password. I am using sql developer for managing my database on the server

I have followed few examples on internet how to create a udl file, but my problem comes in provoding the "data source" for testing the connection. What should go in here?

I am new to oracle and creating connection strings using udl

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but just in case someone is searching for an answer like I was, the Data Source string should be:

```
<server>/<SID>:<port>
```